# Visual Studio C# - tutorial creating project .dll for NUnit

Tags: dll, nunit, project

I am looking for a tutorial where explains how to create a .dll project in Visual Studio for NUnit and how import it to Nunit, **because In Visual Studio I only know to create a C# Console project and there I wrote the C# code for selenium, but to upload it in NUnit I need a .dll file not the "exe" pVisual studio project**

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upload .dll from Visual Studio to NUnit - C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24794657/upload-dll-from-visual-studio-to-nunit-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup this in your project. Click right button on your project 
Propertis->Application->Output type: setup to -> class library.